# Error in starting puppetmaster while upgrade

Tags: linux, ubuntu, puppet

I am trying to upgrade my system (Linux mint 17):

> $ sudo apt-get upgrade

And this is the output, (I have tried this more than once so I am copy+pasting the latest output)

> Reading package lists... Done
>
> Building dependency tree
>
> Reading state information... Done
>
> Calculating upgrade... Done
>
> The following packages have been kept back:
>     facter libqt5gui5 linux-generic linux-headers-generic linux-image-generic
>     mintupdate python-pip
>
> 0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 7 not upgraded.
>
> 1 not fully installed or removed.
>
> After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
>
> Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
>
> Setting up puppetmaster (3.8.1-1puppetlabs1) ...
>
> - Starting puppet master
>
> could not change to group "pe-puppet"
>
> Could not change to user pe-puppet: Invalid user: pe-puppet
>
> invoke-rc.d: initscript puppetmaster, action "start" failed.
>
> dpkg: error processing package puppetmaster (--configure):
>   subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 74
>
> Errors were encountered while processing:
>    puppetmaster
>
> E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

What is the issue with puppetmaster?

Answer (score 0):

```
Could not change to user pe-puppet: Invalid user: pe-puppet
```

This means your system does not have the user (and group) pe-puppet.

You can create the user and group and it should work fine.

```
sudo useradd -U pe-puppet
```